# ¿Problemas al firmar un XML en WCF (C#) con un certificado .PFX?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Estoy tratando de firmar un `XML` a partir de un archivo `.pfx` (sin password) que se encuentra en la carpeta BIN del Servicio `WCF`. Para ello uso la librería `X509Certificate2`. En la maquina de desarrollo no hay problema de hacerlo, accedo al archivo y lo puedo importar/leer, sin embargo, cuando lo implemento en el servidor puedo acceder al archivo pero no lo puedo importar/leer. 
Para comprobar el acceso al archivo `.pfx` uso:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(strRutaCert)==false)
{
    this.Resultado = false;
    this.Mensaje = "El Path del Certificado es inaccesible";
    return;
}
```

Para Importar/Leer:

```
X509Certificate2 objCert = new X509Certificate2();
try
{
    objCert.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(strRutaCert));     
    return objCert;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error al leer certificado: " + ex.Message + ". Ruta: " + argArchivo);
}
```

El mensaje que e arroja la excepción es: `The specified network password is not correct`
Conocen alguna manera de solucionar este error?. Se agradece el aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si le sirve a alguien, lo solucione modificando la instruccion:

```
 objCert.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(strRutaCert),"", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet));
```